# getting Session Id from server side but sending to server side it says (volley.authorize error)

Tags: android, codeigniter, android-volley, session-cookies

we have php(codeIgniter) web application developed using api(web services) i'm trying to develop android app using same api's.
I'm able to login with the web service api call but unable to fetch the json data and getting error 401(unauthorized)

The data fetching web service consists of oauth_timestamp and oauth_nonce and Oauth_token, I'm unable to maintain cookie in android.

I'm using the volley to access web service.

Please help me in resolving this issue soon...

```
public long TimeStamp(){
    /*Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    return ts;*/
    long t = new Date().getTime();
    return (long) Math.floor(t/1000)+3600*12;
}

String CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int length=6;
public String nonce(int length){
    String chars = CHARS;
    String res="";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int rnum = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length());
        res = res + chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

//getting json data and **unable to maintaining session id** token = "ksd934nksdj9sd9sdsdfiu3" secret = "sd2fgi94jfk" **ci_session = "w2jksd23jckjdsdkksdl3kd92kje"**;

```
 String url4 = "http://localhost/app/services/CaptureMeasure/getFacilityListDetail/?oauth_token="+token+"&oauth_token_secret="+secret+"&oauth_consumer_key=www.sthub.com&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp="+TimeStamp()+"&oauth_nonce="+nonce(6)+"&oauth_signature=sthub123456789%26"+secret;
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+last_token+"las----->"+last_secret, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest3 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url4, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG+"---->",response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG,error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Cookie",ci_session);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest3);
```

Comment: Please show your code of what have you done so far so others can check where the bug happens.

Comment: please check the code...:)